# An exercise in Banach Space Theory

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

I am currently reading a book and  while i was reading I came across an exercise :

> Prove that a Banach Space $X$ has finite dimension if and only if every linear subspace of $X$ is closed.

My solution goes like this :

The direction ($\implies$) is immediate since if we have a subspace $F \subseteq X$ then $F$ must be also of finite dimension hence closed.

For the opposite direction I assumed that $X$ has an infinite dimension , then we know that there exist a non trivial linear functional $F:X \to \mathbb{R}$ which is not bounded . Then I proved that $\ker F$ must be dense in $X$ and from hypothesis we have that $\ker F$ is also closed, hence $\ker F=X$ which means that $F$ is trivial and we have a contradiction.

Is this proof correct ? I am asking because I didn't use the hypothesis that $X$ is Banach throughout the proof.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your result is correct, and it holds for any normed (not necessarily complete) vector space

Comment: Yes it is. However you are based in a fact "strong" enough which is the existence of a not bounded linear functional (try to show one, it would be better).

Comment: @Piquito Yes you are right an example of such a functional is :  Let $H$ be an  inifinite hamel basis of $X$ then i can write $H$ as $H = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{z_i : i \in I\}$ where $\{x_n : n \in  \mathbb{N}\}$ is countable part of the basis and $\{z_i : i \in I\}$ the rest part of the basis.(Actually if $X$ is banach space then we now for sure that $\{z_i : i \in I\}$ is uncountable). Then i define $F:X \to \mathbb{R}$ with $F(x_n)=n||x_n||$ and $F(z_i)=0$ and since $H$ is hamel basis there is a unique linear expansion of $F$. Now clearly $F$ is not bounded.

Comment: The intresting would be with the exercise can be prooved without contradiction.

Comment: @demOnakos: A linear function  not continuous is something "teratological" because it is not continuous at any point. However, in the space of derivable functions of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb R$ with the norm of supremum, an operator as familiar as the derivative is an example. Regards.

Comment: @demOnakos If possible, may i know book are you reading?

Comment: @idonknow It's a book that we are getting in our undergraduate program in the university of Athens (Greece) , meaning that the book is in greek language :P ( if you are still interested i can give you more information )